# Handling possible advertisements

Tags: support

While doing reviews I noticed this [answer.](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/2793/233)  Innocent enough yet an odd answer for someone so new, upon checking their history I found [another](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60940) (their only other answer) that is nearly identical to this one and happens to be on the Blender site...

To me it seems an awful lot like an advertisement but whoever viewed the flag marked it as not spam.  At what point is it?  The only contributions to the site are both links to the same website.

Answer (score 2):

I've added a comment to the answer asking whether or not they are affiliated with the site. If they are, it might still make a valid answer, but they should always disclose their affiliation. In principle, it can be acceptable to [post about your own website or product](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) so long as it makes a valid answer.

> The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.